# Rotating binaries viewing geometry

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, gravitational-waves, ligo

I am reading [this article](https://doi.org/10.1063/PT.3.4090)
and looking at eq. (4). I am not sure how the expressions in terms of the viewing angle $\iota$ and the phase $\Phi$ are achieved. It looks to me like it has nothing to do with general relativity but with geometrical definitions. Let the gravitational wave amplitude be
$$ h_0 \equiv \frac{4c}{D} \left( \frac{G \cal{M}}{c^3} \right) \Omega^{2/3} .$$ Then the expressions are

$$h_+ = h_0 \cdot \frac{1}{2} (1+\cos^2\iota)\cos 2\Phi(t)$$

$$ h_x = h_0 \cdot  \cos\iota \sin 2\Phi(t).$$

The angles are related to how we observe the waves, and I am not sure how they come about.

Comment: Are you asking about what these angles represent or about how the dependence of the strain on these angles comes about?

Comment: I am asking about the exact dependence (cosine / sine expressions of the appropriate parameters). Thanks

Comment: I found the following reference (eq. 3.22):
https://dcc.ligo.org/public/0106/T1300666/003/Whelan_geometry.pdf
a lot more involved than I thought...